# Managing conditional redirect_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, if-statement

I have multiple user types in a system that shows each user different views and templates of the stored information, often based on whether they are logged in and what current_user.user_type is. As a result, I have lots of this:

```
#controller
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
if current_user.user_type == "Company"
  redirect_to :controller => "companies", :action => "home"
elsif current_user.user_type == "Contractor"
  @contractor = Contractor.find(current_user.user_type_id)
  redirect_to :controller => "contractors", :action => "home"
elsif current_user.user_type == "Customer"
  redirect_to :controller => "companies", :action => "list"
end
```

This is my first Rails project and I am pretty sure this is poor design. What are simple clean ways of doing this in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having **a lot** of code like this, is a code smell that your controller is really serving multiple purposes. Assuming your controller is something like InfoController, which is a REST view for some Info model, ask yourself:

- What is the central piece of your actions, the data or the user who access
  it?
- Are you taking decisions based on who
  requests the actions? (Like saving,
  deleting, etc)
- Can these decisions be taken in the
  Info model, rather than in the controller?

To me, seems like you should create different controllers for each model, and make just one redirect per action. In your views, you can use things like [polymorphic_paths](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url) to link up to your controllers.

If you decide not to do this, I'd just put that code in a `case` statement instead of an `if`.

Comment: Chubas, it seems to me that I should just do the case statement. I have places where, for example, someone signs in as a user but they are redirected to a different controller's home page depending on their user_type. If this is simply a redirect issue (and not a data decision one) then a case statement should be sufficient. Does this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

Can also use constraints as seen here: [User-centric Routing in Rails 3](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/05/31/user-centric-routing-in-rails-3/)

```
root :to => "companies#home", :constraints => UserTypeConstraint.new("Company")
```

Or scoped routes as seen here: [Use lambdas for Rails 3 Route Constraints](http://intridea.com/posts/use-lambdas-for-rails3-route-constraints)

```
scope :constraints => lambda{|req| !req.session[:company_user_id].blank? } do
  # all company routes
end
```

Answer (score -3):

When a  user hit login in your application, you must have some code to redirect them somewhere.
This is where you want to put your code.
and you probably want to use:

```
redirect_to companies_path
```